# WebAPI controller not working while another one does

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have an API that works fine locally and when I move it to the live environment it doesn't.

The main POST action on the affected controller returns:

```
NotFound
```

With a test GET action I get back:

```
"Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
```

Strangely, when I uploaded a testController with the same test action as used in the main controller I get a proper response from the API.

This is the test that works fine:

```cs
public class TestController : ApiController
{

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage helloWorld()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "HelloWorld!");
    }
}
```

The controller which does not work:

```cs
public class DeviceController : ApiController
{

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage helloWorld() // This returns: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://api.mySite.com/api/Device/helloWorld'."
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "HelloWorld!");
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Login([FromBody] LoginObject loginObject) // This returns: "NotFound"
    {
        ...
    }
```

}

Here is the web config:

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(

            name: "API Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: So `http://api.mySite.com/api/Test/helloWorld` works, right?

Comment: yeah indeed, I get "HelloWorld!" back.  This seems so odd... got to be a routing issue?

Comment: Hmm... lets check it. try to add route attribute `[Route("api/Device/helloWorld")]`

Comment: ahh, ok it is now working.  I wonder why the routing for the other controller is ok without explicitly declaring it... Feel free to add this as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add explicitly declare of route like by acrion

```
[Route("api/Device/helloWorld")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage helloWorld()
```

or

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Device")]
public class DeviceController : ApiController
```

and then

```
[Route("helloWorld")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage helloWorld()
```

Comment: Explicitly declaring the routes solved this issue for me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For poor sap's like myself in the future: Ensure the methods on your controller are public.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time looking for the answer to this problem in .NET 7.0 after I had made a new project (which automatically created a `WeatherForecastController`).

It turns out that the project had also automatically created a file named *proxy.conf.js*. In the file, the `context:` setting was set to `"/weatherforecast"`. I changed it to `"/api"` instead and then changed `[Route("[controller]")]` to `[Route("api/[controller]")]` in both controller files. The controllers worked fine after that.